# Is this a mistake in the definition of Liouville's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

In my book the theorem of Liouville is defined as follows:

Let $f\in H(\mathbb{C})$ and $f(z)=O(|z|^m)$ with $m\in \mathbb{N}_0$ then $f$ is a polynomial with $deg(f) \leq m$.

Shouldn't it be $|f(z)|= O(|z|^m)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a positive function $g$, the expression $f(z)=O(g(z))$ means $|f(z)|\le Mg(z)$ for sufficiently large $|z|$. So the absolute value on the function $f$ would be redundant.